# Creating a custom tabBarIcon has blue tint when selected, and selected icon moves

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to create a custom tabBar that looks like this. [image]

In xcode, this is all I have been able to achieve.

[image]

I am using this code to get the selected image.

```
self.searchTabBarItem.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search-TabBarButton-Selected@3x.png"];
        [self.searchTabBarItem.selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Still not working as planned. I don't know how to get the blue tint away.
Also, the search icon seems to move to the right a few pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so silly.

```
self.searchTabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-TabBarButton-Selected@3x.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

The icon still moves to the right a bit though. I'll figure that out.